# Nginx Kuberentes are not adding auto slash on url

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, nginx-config

I have an issue with three vuejs applications which should run in one nginx image, run on Kubernetes and configured with nginx ingress for URL in web.
Everything works fine but the only issue is if the applications will be run without slash tehn I am getting this https://tools-dev.dmix.cloud:8080/magic3d/ but if I add thie slash in the end then it works perfectly https://tools-dev.dmix.cloud/magic3d/. I would like that it works also without slash in the end so https://tools-dev.dmix.cloud/magic3d. I tried a lot of thinks but it will not work can anybody helps me please?
Following my files:

At first create docker images:

```
FROM  nexus-docker.colordigital.cloud/dev-tools/ubuntu:20.04 as packages

RUN  apt-get update; apt-get install curl -y
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y unzip
# use on build arg dev int or prod i.e. docker build --build-arg stage=dev . 
ARG stage

WORKDIR /moodboard

RUN if [ "$stage" = "dev" ] ; then \
 echo "dev moodboard" && curl -k -u XXXXXXXXX JENKINS/dist.zip --output ./dist.zip \
    ; elif [ "$stage" = "int" ]; then \
  echo "int moodboard" && curl -k -u XXXXXXXXX JENKINS/dist.zip --output ./dist.zip  \
  ; elif [ "$stage" = "prod" ]; then \
  echo "prod moodboard" &&  curl -k -u XXXXXXXXX JENKINS/dist.zip ./dist.zip \
  ;fi


RUN unzip dist.zip


WORKDIR ../magic3d
RUN if [ "$stage" = "dev" ] ; then \ 
echo "dev magic3d" &&  curl -k -u XXXXXXXXX JENKINS/dist.zip. \
; elif [ "$stage" = "int" ]; then \
echo "int magic3d" &&  curl -k -u XXXXXXXXX JENKINS/dist.zip \
  ; elif [ "$stage" = "prod" ]; then \
echo "prod magic3d" && curl -k -u XXXXXXXXX JENKINS/dist.zip  \
  ;fi
RUN  unzip dist.zip


WORKDIR ../measure
RUN  if [ "$stage" = "dev" ] ; then \  
echo "dev measure" && curl -k -u XXXXXXXXX JENKINS/dist.zip  \
; elif [ "$stage" = "int" ]; then \
echo "int measure" && curl -k -u XXXXXXXXX JENKINS/dist.zip \
; elif [ "$stage" = "prod" ]; then \
echo "prod measure" && curl -k -u XXXXXXXXX JENKINS/dist.zip \
;fi
RUN   unzip dist.zip


FROM   nexus-docker.colordigital.cloud/dev-tools/nginx-unpriv:1.20
ARG stage
EXPOSE 8080:8080





COPY ${stage}-config_tools.json  /usr/share/nginx/html/config_tools.json

COPY  --from=packages /moodboard/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/moodboard
COPY  --from=packages /magic3d/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/magic3d
COPY  --from=packages /measure/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/measure
```

All of this three applications run fine with / in the end but if I am running without slash then the issues appears. Static web files will be downloaded from Jenkins therfore I wrote XXX for security measures.

Then I am configuring these on NGINX Controller on Kuberentes (after creatung deployment and Service files but these are not important here only the ingress file)

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress
  namespace: dev
  annotations:

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: >-
      DNT,X-CustomHeader,X-LANG,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,X-Api-Key,X-Device-Id,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,api_key,
      Authorization, bearer
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: '*'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - dev-env.colordigital.cloud
      secretName: tls-secret
    - hosts:
        - tools-dev.dmix.cloud
      secretName: tls-secret-dmix
  rules:

    - host: tools-dev.dmix.cloud
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: dev-tools
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Thanks Guys.

Comment: It seems that both the links are working. Moreover you can go through below documentation and understand how paths behaves

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/basic-configuration/#new-features-available-in-kubernetes-118-and-above

Comment: But  if you delete the slash in the end it will not work dev.dmix.cloud/magic3d it will redirect to port 8080